# Как написать функцию delete по индексу, delete по Nod-у, конструктор и деструктор для класса List?

Tags: c++, классы, списки

Немного набросков, но не знаю правильно ли

### F_list.h

```
#ifndef F_LIST_H
#define F_LIST_H
struct Node{
  int value;
  Node* next;
  Node* prev;
};
class F_list{
public:
  void deleteInd(int);
  void deleteNod(Node);
  ~F_list();
private:
  Node* head;
  Node* tail;
};

#endif // F_LIST_H
```

### F_List.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
#include "f_list.h"

F_list::F_list()
  :head(nullptr), tail(nullptr)
{
}

F_list::~F_list(){

}
void F_list::deleteNod(Node n){

  n->next = nullptr;
  n->prev = nullptr;
  delete n;
}
void F_list::deleteInd(int i){

}
```

Comment: Нет, deleteNod явно неправильный, так как удаляя нод, нужно позаботиться, чтобы связать предыдущий со следующим.

Comment: Конструктор
this.head =head;
this.tail=tail.
if(this.head!=nullptr)
this.head.next=tail;
if(this.tail!=nullptr)
this.tail.next=head;

Comment: @HasmikGaryaka, а как удалить тогда нод?

Comment: @HasmikGaryaka, а что вы написали про констурктор, эти ифы в том случае когда только имеем хед и тейл?

Comment: Попробуйте нарисовать это на бумаге, тогда легче написать. Нод как прямоугольник, разбитый на сегменты, связи между нодами.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
void F_list::deleteNod(Node n){
  n->prev->next=n->next;
  n->next->prev=n->prev;
  n->next = nullptr;
  n->prev = nullptr;
  delete n;
}
void F_list::deleteInd(int i){
    Node curr;
    if (head!=nullptr) 
   {
    curr=head;       
   for (int j=0;j<i;j++)
    {
       if(curr->next==nullptr) break;
          curr=curr->next;
    }
     if (curr!=nullptr) deleteNod(curr);
}
}
```

Comment: только там по-моему Node*cure

Comment: Node*curr = new Node;

Comment: и если curr = head, не получится что у нас два head-а?

Comment: хм, или потом все равно curr удалиться, и останется один хед

Comment: и еще один вопрос, если curr->nex == nullptr, он не удаляется вообще?

Comment: и последний вопрос, можно в деструкторе просто вызову deleteNod(n)?

Comment: head и curr - это указатели, поэтому будут 2 указателя на ту же область памяти. Это не страшно.  если curr->nex == nullptr значит, это нулевой указатель, его нельзя удалять, а не то будет крэш.